# Drawing the complex equation $|z|=\arg z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Letting $z=x+iy$ I have
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\tan^{-1}\frac yx$$ After that I don't have any idea what to do? Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Things are much much easier in polar coordinates: $\rho=\theta$ is an Archimedean spiral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the problem to polar coordinates,
$$z = re^{i\theta}$$
$|z| = r$ and $arg(z) = \theta$

Hence in the $(r,\theta)$ plane you have a spiral  $$r = \theta $$

Comment: $r=\theta$ is a spiral not a line.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using Cartesian coordinates, we can use polar coordinates to get a one-line solution:
$$r=\theta$$
This describes an Archimedean spiral starting from the origin and moving outwards a distance of $2\pi$ per turn.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Feeling stupid thinking why this simple idea didn't cross my mind.